# Is there a mod or another solution that can keep me from accidentally stealing stuff?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I hate it when I go to talk to someone, but I click just a few pixels too far to the side and end up accidentally stealing a plate or a wooden bowl.  The next thing I know, I have a bounty on my head and a guard breathing down my throat.  Now I have to reload my last save.  It would be great if there were a mod or another way to not accidentally steal certain items like skulls, bowls, and plates.

Comment: (if on pc) I *know* you can clear your bounty etc with the console, I just don't know how to do it right off.

Comment: I am about tempted to do that.  I am tired of every guard saying, "Wait, I know you" and trying to confiscate my stolen goods because I accidentally five-fingered a plate while trying to talk to someone who was sitting at a table.  I guess the alternative would be to drop all stole stuff, pay the bounty, and then pick it all back up again.

Comment: I hate it when I accidently steal stuff too. Especially when they remove all my stolen goods. I lost like 3 of my best weapons before because of accidently stealing stuff and getting caught doing it (I also lose around 600-1400 gold worth of gems)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes there is, [blocksteal redux](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/61605) will prevent you from stealing. 3,670 endorsements, too, so it should be pretty good.

To remove your bounty via console use the [paycrimegold](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_%28Skyrim%29) command:

> player.paycrimegold `<X> <Y> <FactionID>`
>
> Sometimes, does not pay off your bounty fully.
> X = 1 Remove stolen items. 0 Don't remove stolen items.
> Y = 1 Go to jail.  0 Don't go to jail.

Comment: I installed this using the mod manager and it doesn't work.  As soon as I stole something, I had a guard all up in my business in no time.  I checked to make sure the mod was enabled, too.  I have Skyrim 1.9.32 and SKSE 1.6.16 build 44.

Comment: Did you activate it via the spell?

Comment: Win!  I activated it through the mod config menu and now I am not able to pick up any owned items.  I'd have though it would have been enabled by default.

Comment: Haha yeah, it was designed to give you flexibility in case if you wanted to steal in the future :)

Comment: Also, for the SSE edition there is the similar mod:  https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/18732